# My <div> below <header> is going INVISIBLE when the user scrolls down, along with <header> (only header should go invisible). Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, material-design-lite

**[JsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/r8xn9aua/33/)**

I am using [Material Design Lite](https://getmdl.io/started/). Now in the header, I need a `Title` row, a row which shows description (labelled `Story` and then `Story story story...` in the following screenshot), and then a row which is the tabs bar.

Now I also want the Material Design Lite's [waterfall header effect](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section), in which all header rows except the `Title` row go invisible as the user scrolls down. But I want it in a way that the tabs row (tabs bar, the one which show tabs' headers/titles) remains visible, just like the `Title` row as the user scrolls down.

***What I tried:***

I thought that removing the tabs bar from the `<header>` and placing it right below the header (and giving it the same `background-color` etc. as the header ) will make the tab bar appear to the user as a part of the header, but since it will actually Not be a part of the header, so it will not get the `waterfall` effect, i.e. it will not go invisible when the user scrolls down the page.

**But to my surprise, even when I do not put the `section.tabs-bar` inside the `<header>`, it still gets the waterfall effect, i.e. it still goes invisible when the user scrolls down the page.**

**So the question is that what should I do? How to make the `section.tabs-bar` NOT go invisible when the user scrolls down the page.**

***VERY IMPORTANT NOTE:***

In JSFiddle, the output panel is small, and since Material Design Lite is responsive, so the header row of `Title` and that of description is not displayed at all. But I am adding screenshots of what it looks like on localhost.

***When the user has NOT scrolled:***

[image]

***WHEN THE USER HAS SCROLLED DOWN THE PAGE:***

[image]

Comment: you don't want to hide the header full right ?

Comment: JSfiddle not accurate

Comment: @Naila No! I don't want the _tab-bar_ to hide. It is a `<section class="mdl-tabs mdl-js-tabs" >` (the bar/row which contains `ALPHA`, `BETA` and `GAMMA` tab titles) BELOW the `<header>`.

Comment: @ChrisHappy Why not? What's wrong with it?

Comment: @Ali Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @ChrisHappy The fiddle I posted is exactly what an SSCCE is. I wrote it for the purpose of posting it on SO. BTW your link results in `Page Not Found` -> not accurate! =P

Comment: can you provide your working url?

Comment: @user7357089 It's on localhost

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: move the `.task-bar` out of the `main` [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8xn9aua/34/)

**Update**: Add this CSS:

```
.mdl-layout__content {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mdl-tabs.is-upgraded .mdl-tabs__panel {
  overflow-y:scroll;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8xn9aua/37/)

Comment: Hey you messed up my tabs. In your fiddle, scroll to the bottom of the page, and you will see that the content of each tab (in different colors) is displayed one after the other, in the body of only one tab.

Comment: You do understand what I want. Thing is, those `ALPHA`, `BETA` and `GAMMA` are headers of _tabs_. Please compare my fiddle with yours. In _my_ fiddle, clicking on `BETA` will _hide_ previously displayed tab content, and display new tab content (with a yellowish background color, compared to previous reddish background color). Likewise clicking on `GAMMA` will reveal content different from previously displayed content (this one has background color of grey)

Comment: @Sie Now in _your_ fiddle, run the code and then scroll down the output window. The content for all the three tabs is displayed in the place for content for the first tab, that is pink, then yellow and then grey content. AND clicking on other tab headers (i.e. `BETA` and `GAMMA`) does not reveal anything.

Comment: It is an MCVE. JS comes from the external resource `material.min.js`. In the left side menu, expand the node titled `External Resources` on the JSFiddle website.

Comment: Anyways, the important thing here is that you messed up my tabs. =P Fix them =P

Comment: About the note you added in the question, I was joking. I am sorry!

Comment: Like I mentioned in the question, I CAN NOT use a _fixed height_ because that way, the waterfall effect gets removed from the header as well. I DO NOT want that.

Comment: It's a responsive height. 1vh is equal to 1% of the height of the container. -50px is for the header on the top. Just use @media tags to adjust it when the title gets added.